# Can we still earn hats if we deactivate them using "I hate hats"?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I can deactivate the hats using the "I hate hats" link, but I wonder if we can still earn them if we fulfill the requirements.

> [image: Here a screenshot]

Comment: @Emna correct, I reopened it now. The other question only mentions that you don't lose hats earned *before* you opted out. This is about what happens *during* the opt out period. I'll do a short test now.

Comment: From your profile it looks like you love hats

Comment: Haha yes you are right :p

Comment: I took off my Winter Bash hat in remembrance of the princess. MTFBWY.

Comment: __YES__ in short.

Comment: Already answered ! but thanks anyway  @HardikVaghani

Comment: @Emna There is no word "desactivate" in the English language. The previous editors had it correct with "deactivate". You might be falling into the trap [explained here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080613185903AAtXfGo).

Comment: ok @MikeMcCaughan thanks for the information ! combined with french tongue that's whyi thought it 's desactivate !

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, I just tested it by

- opting out for hats
- upvoting two answers on Meta sites
- waiting long enough for the hat script to award the hats (I was even removed from the leaderboard)
- opting in for hats

Immediately after opting in, I received a notification for two new hats.

[image: YAY! MOAR HATZ!!]

Comment: That's cool ! thanks a lot for making things clear for me in meta !

Comment: You're welcome. You'll see that most of these Meta questions you have, have already been asked, but this is definitely a good and original one.

Comment: @Glorfinel's your example is also original one!

Comment: When to kind person meets.