# Is the number of hats displayed in your profile page always equal to the number of hats earned in your main community?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I have 6 hats on my main community (Stack Overflow), but only 2 in the Drupal community. In my profile on Drupal, I see a number of hats equal to 6.

Is that because I have six hats on SO?

[image]

Comment: why a negative vote ? shall i explain more ? some thing not clear?

Comment: Meta has a bit of a different culture than the main site. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus) for some insights. You may want to take a bit of time to observe and get used to Meta before fully engaging and posting questions/answers.

Comment: The down votes are from the three users that hate hats ...

Comment: @rene i guess that also ! but it 's not fair haha

Comment: @rene : at least i have a good question with those hats :D  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340345/can-we-still-earn-hats-if-we-deactivated-them-using-i-hate-hats

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This number is indeed the total number of *distinct* hats you earned on *all* sites. To check the number of hats your earned on a specific site, you'll need to look at the [leaderboard](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/drupal.stackexchange.com).

Another way to look at this is that it is the possible number of hats you can *wear* on a site (after all, if you click on the hat, the 'change hat' dialog opens). You can wear hats you earned on Stack Overflow on another site (e.g. Drupal Answers).

Comment: you have sais :'This number is indeed the total number of hats you earned on all sites.'  but in total i earned 11 in all sites but 6 in stackoverflow which is shown

Comment: Sorry, forgot the word *distinct* there.